# highcharts xaxis label data display

Tags: highcharts, label

The date displayed on the highcharts xaxis label is showing non-existent dates, not actual data. What should be set on the xaxis label to show the existing date values?

My code is below.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('dataChart', {
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        rangeSelector: {
                            selected: 5
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: result[0].chartRptCdNm
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            type: "datetime",
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function() {
                                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.value);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: result[0].graphYaxis
                            },
                            opposite: false,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            margin: 0,
                            labels: {
                                format: '{value}' + result[0].graphYaxisUnit,
                                align: "right",
                                y: -5,
                                x: -5
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: "",
                            useHTML: true,
                            valueDecimals: 2,
                            split: true,
                            formatter: function () {
                                var s = "";
                                
                                $.each(this.points, function() {
                                    s += '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + ';">\u25CF</span><b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>';
                                    s += '<span style="font-size: 13px"> 일자 : ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', new Date(this.x)) + '</span><br/>';
                                    s += '<span style="font-size: 13px"> 금리 : ' + (Math.floor(this.y * 100) / 100) + '</span><br/>';
                                });
                                return s;
                            }
                        },
                        series: seriesArr
                    });
```

I am making a chart using a single line series.

Comment: Hi @해품달, Please provide me with a sample of your data structure.

Comment: The data structure is as shown in the link below.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq2eE97Jz68MjAm8nKux24bOSl52?e=dBFLyu

Some data may have the same data on different dates, and some data may not exist.
But I'm getting the xAxis label for a date that doesn't exist.

Can't the labels of non-existing dates not be displayed, only the labels of existing dates?